# Is it popular to omit "as" while using "consider this one that one"?

Tags: meaning

I found an interesting quote in this [post](https://quotestats.com/topic/pinkroot-quotes/).

> I believe if we love something and have fun, we tend to self teach and
>   learn at a rapid rate. I also consider confusion a starting state for
>   learning. It opens us to new patterns emerging. - Author: Todd Rice

Is it necessary to insert an "as" into "consider confusion a starting state" which produces "consider confusion as a starting state"?

... or thanks to [@TrevorD's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/496534/is-it-popular-to-omit-as-while-using-consider-this-one-that-one#comment1197516_496534), insert "to be" into "consider confusion a starting state" which produces "consider confusion to be a starting state"?

The key is to insert something, in case someone has unclear pronunciation, low voice.

Comment: Why do you choose "as" as a possibly missing word? One could equally suggest that the sentence should be "I also consider confusion *to be* a starting state ...".  It's not unusual to elide some words in mid-sentence in this way.

Comment: Unlike the verb "regard", which only takes "as", with "consider" we can either use or omit "as".